# Sequentially numbering a nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, index

I've got a nested list

```
{a, b, {c, d}, e, {f, {g, h}}}
```

which I want to magically transmogrify to

```
{{1,a}, {2,b}, {{3,c}, {4,d}}, {5,e}, {{6,f}, {{7,g}, {8,h}}}}
```

This is just prepending a simple sequence to each element regardless of depth.  I can't think of any simple way to do this in general.  My stubbornly procedural brain keeps thinking of loops and recursion, but I'm sure you more functional types have a much better trick up your sleeve.

Comment: Will the elements be unique? This is a killer condition for some solutions using `ReplaceAll`.

Comment: I think your question as stated is not entirely well specified: would you want `{{a**x},b}` to be replaced with `{{{1,a**x}},{2, b}}` or `{{{1, a}**{2, x}},{3,b}}`? You should note that the answers given will not all do the same thing for cases like that. I'd expect this could bite you once using it in practice...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I am pretty sure that it is not the best solution but how about this?

```
numbering[x_] := Block[{n = 0}, Replace[x, y_ :> {++n, y}, {-1}]]
```

Some example outputs:

```
In[1]:= numbering[{a, b, {c, d}, e, {f, {g, h}}}]

Out[1]= {{1, a}, {2, b}, {{3, c}, {4, d}}, {5, e}, {{6, f}, {{7, g}, {8, h}}}}

In[2]:= numbering[Nest[{#, #} &, x, 3]]

Out[2]= {{{{1, x}, {2, x}}, {{3, x}, {4, x}}}, {{{5, x},
    {6, x}}, {{7, x}, {8, x}}}}
```

About the level spec `{-1}` (per [reference](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Replace.html)):

> Level -1 consists of numbers, symbols, and other objects that do not have subparts.

Sounds exactly like what you want.

Comment: Your replace is safer than mine :P. +1!

Comment: +1 for the `{-1}` level spec, which I had no idea existed until now. The consequences may never be the same!

Comment: @Pillsy Very nice use of negative levspec, indeed. There was a question on SO asked way back about it as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998797/how-do-you-interpret-negative-levels-in-mathematica . In addition to the docs, it is also briefly discussed [here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node79.html). Another interesting IMO (shameless plug :)) use of it is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958128/arbitrarily-deep-nested-pattern-matching/5961851#5961851)

Comment: Use of `Block` here is incorrect; it should be `Module`.  Look what happens when `numbering[{{a, b}, {m, n}}]` is used.

Answer (score 22):

This is the same basic method as already presented by Yu-Sung Chang, but `Map` is more concise.
More significantly using `Block` is incorrect:  if `n` appears in the input it will be incorrectly substituted.

Instead I would write:

```
expr = {a, b, {c, d}, e, {f, {g, h}}};

Module[{i = 1},
  Map[{i++, #} &, expr, {-1}]
]
```

> ```
> {{1, a}, {2, b}, {{3, c}, {4, d}}, {5, e}, {{6, f}, {{7, g}, {8, h}}}}
> ```

Comment: MapIndexed is even cleaner: MapIndexed[{First@#2, #1} &, expr, {-1}]

Comment: @GustavoDelfino: That does not work with nested lists, which get all numbered with the top-level index -> {{1, a}, {2, b}, {{3, c}, {3, d}}, {4, e}, {{5, f}, {{5, g}, {5, h}}}}

Comment: @yves-klett: you are right. I works in the example shown but not for deeper lists.

Answer (score 18):

we can also use the `Listable` attribute of `Function`:

```
i = 1;
Function[, {i++, #}, Listable]@{a, b, {c, d}, e, {f, {g, h}}}
```

or(just to explore the `Listable` nature):

```
i = 1;
Function[, {##}, Listable][i++//Unevaluated, {a, b, {c, d}, e, {f, {g, h}}}]
```

output:

```
{{1, a}, {2, b}, {{3, c}, {4, d}}, {5, e}, {{6, f}, {{7, g}, {8, h}}}}
```

Comment: Whoa! `Function[, {i++, #},...]` screams syntax error at me without the parameter or a matching `&` and even the front-end highlights it in red, yet it works! Could you add a short explanation of how your construct works?

Comment: Empty arguments are equivalent to argument `Null`, so `Function[,#,Listable]` is actually `Function[Null,#,Listable]`, which explains why it's not a syntax error (also `Get` sometimes complains, so Id' recommend to insert the `Null`). That form for `Function` will let you define attribtes with the last argument without forcing named arguments, which sometimes is very helpful. AFAIK this is not documented but has appeared in several posts to mathgroup and maybe also stack exchange. As for the syntax-checker of the front-end: it obviously just doesn't know about that undocumented feature...

Comment: @AlbertRetey Thanks, that makes sense :)

Comment: Very good answer. From `Trace`'ing `Listable` functions operating on homogeneous arrays I'd become used to `Thread` being invoked, so I expected this to work differently than it actually does. A definite +1 for revealing that `Listable` still holds a few surprises.

Comment: I had thought `Listable` is parallelized internally. +1

Answer (score 14):

With `ReplaceAll` and `Increment` you can do it:

```
i = 1;
{a, b, {c, d}, e, {f, {g, h}}} /. p : Except[List]?AtomQ :> {i++, p}
```

> ```
> {{1, a}, {2, b}, {{3, c}, {4, d}}, {5, e}, {{6, f}, {{7, g}, {8, h}}}}
> ```

This works if `a`, `b`, etc are simple symbols... maybe is not what you need.

Answer (score 13):

I've never had a need for the [`MapAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapAll.html) (or `//@`) function, but this seems to be a case where it can be used:

```
i=0;
f[x_Symbol] := {++i, x};
f[x_List] := x

f //@ {a, b, {c, d}, e, {f, {g, h}}}
(* {{1, a}, {2, b}, {{3, c}, {4, d}}, {5, e}, {{6, f}, {{7, g}, {8, h}}}} *)
```

Comment: I'm searching for a case where `MapAll` is the answer function. Have you found it yet? With this case it's excessive as you can `Map` with levelspec `{-1}`. (I like the example though, it teaches.)

Comment: @BoLe Yes, certainly `Map` is the better solution, but I posted this 2 weeks after the others... all the obvious ones were taken :) As for `MapAll`, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5747742) and its answers. Some good examples in there.

Answer (score 11):

It's a little on the hairy side, but you can do it functionally (i.e., without mutating a counter) by first finding all the leaves using `Position`, and then replacing what you find at those positions one by one using `Fold`:

```
tree = {a, b, {c, d}, e, {f, {g, h}}};

Module[{indexLeaf},
 With[{indexedPositions = Transpose[
       {Range@Length@#, #}] &@Position[tree, _, {-1}, Heads -> False]},
  indexLeaf[tree_, {index_, position_}] :=
   MapAt[{index, #} &, tree, position]; 
  Fold[indexLeaf, tree, indexedPositions]]]
```

> ```
> {{1, a}, {2, b}, {{3, c}, {4, d}}, {5, e}, {{6, f}, {{7, g}, {8, h}}}}
> ```

**EDIT** to add:

There's an alternative solution that may be a litle cleaner. It uses `ReplacePart`  to make all the changes in one swell foop instead of relying on the ugly `Fold`/`MapAt` combo. Factoring things a bit:

```
ClearAll[indexedLeafPositions, indexedLeafRules, indexLeaves];

indexedLeafPositions[tree_] :=
  Transpose[{#, Range@Length@#}] &@
   Position[tree, _, {-1}, Heads -> False];

indexedLeafRules[tree_] :=
  Cases[indexedLeafPositions@tree,
   {pos_, n_} :> (pos -> {n, Extract[tree, pos]})];

indexLeaves[tree_] :=
 ReplacePart[tree, indexedLeafRules@tree];
```

Trying it out:

```
indexLeaves[tree]
```

> ```
> {{1, a}, {2, b}, {{3, c}, {4, d}}, {5, e}, {{6, f}, {{7, g}, {8, h}}}}
> ```

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps

```
Module[{k = 0},
 Replace[{a, b, {c, d}, e, {f, {g, h}}}
  , i_ :> With[{index = ++k}, {i, index}/;True], {-1}]]


{{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {{c, 3}, {d, 4}}, {e, 5}, {{f, 6}, {{g, 7}, {h, 8}}}}
```

Comment: Looks exactly like mine except `With`. Why do you need it?

Comment: @Yu-SungChang You don't really need it. In fact, this wasn't my intention, I'll edit now (added the `/;True`). For nested lists, it's the same, but this would work even if instead of `List` you have nested `Hold`s or heads that don't evaluate. Because the replacement is done with the counter already incremented and evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

Another side-effect free functional solution without a counter variable:

```
expr = {a, b, {c, d}, e, {f, {g, h}}};
MapIndexed[{#2,#1}&,expr,{-1}] /. MapThread[Rule, {Position[expr,_,{-1},Heads->False], Range[Count[expr,_,{-1}]]}]
```

`MapIndexed` first associates each atomic expression with its multi-index position in `expr`. Then `ReplaceAll` applies transformation rules to transform each multi-index position to a single-index position.

If the expression is large, using DownValues instead of transformation rules is much faster:

```
Module[{multiToSingleIndex},
  MapIndexed[(multiToSingleIndex[#1]=First@#2)&,Position[expr,_,{-1},Heads->False]];
  MapIndexed[{multiToSingleIndex[#2],#1}&,expr,{-1}]
]
```

Comment: I can't see any reason that one would *not* want to use a counter variable as it is the natural way to do this in one pass.  Nevertheless if one chooses not to I would do this a bit differently.  Your first code will fail if one of the depth specifications appears literally in the original `expr`.  Your second code looks solid.  You could write the first instead like this: `ReplacePart[expr, 
 MapIndexed[# -> {#2[[1]], Extract[expr, #]} &, Position[expr, _, {-1}, Heads -> False]]]`

Comment: Most code using counters makes assumptions about the evaluation order (e.g., `Map`), which Mathematica does not explicitly guarantee.

Comment: Sakra, that is not a problem.  The standard expression evaluation rules of *Mathematica* apply.  As the documentation says: "`Map` always effectively constructs a complete new expression, and then evaluates it."  Therefore the code in my answer effectively produces: `{({i++, #1} &)[a], ({i++, #1} &)[b], {({i++, #1} &)[c], ({i++, #1} &)[d]}, ({i++, #1} &)[e], {({i++, #1} &)[f], {({i++, #1} &)[g], ({i++, #1} &)[h]}}}` -- the evaluation order of which is not ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

```
Partition[Riffle[Range[Length[Flatten[{a, b, {c, d}, e, {f, {g, h}}}]]], 
    Flatten[{a, b, {c, d}, e, {f, {g, h}}}]], 2]
(* {{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}, {4, d}, {5, e}, {6, f}, {7, g}, {8, h}} *)
```

Comment: Your solution does not preserve original structure of the list, so it does not fit OP's requirements (see the question).