# Numbering nested list according with Depth (or Level)

Tags: list-manipulation, index

(This question is slightly similar with [*Sequentially numbering a nested list*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3585/17), but not exactly the same.)

## What I want

Say I have a nested list

```
lst = {{"X", {{"X", "X"}, {{"X", "X"}, "X"}, "X"}, "X"}, "X", "X"};
```

What I would like to do is to label each `"X"` with a number according with its `Depth`/`Level`, that is something like this

```
{{{2,"X"},{{{4,"X"},{4,"X"}},{{{5,"X"},{5,"X"}},{4,"X"}},{3,"X"}},{2,"X"}},{1,"X"},{1,"X"}}
```

## What I tried

I used a dumb way to achieve my goal.

First I label each `"X"` with a unique label:

```
labelLst = lst /. "X" :> RandomReal[]
```

Then get their positions:

```
posSet = Position[labelLst, #][[1]] & /@ Flatten[labelLst]
```

Then label `"X"`s with its `Depth`:

```
ReplacePart[lst, Function[pos, pos -> {
     Length[pos], lst[[##]] & @@ pos
     }] /@ posSet]
```

## My question

I think taking the aid of extra real-number labels is a bit cheating and inelegant, so I want to ask for a more elegant method for this. By saying *elegant*, I'm thinking of something pure list-manipulations. Any idea would be helpful.

---

**Why I need this:**

I'm trying to format the result of `Trace` for external plain-text viewer. Label numbers according with `Level`s eventually lead to human friendly indents.

```
Clear[levelIndentFunc]
levelIndentFunc[lst_] :=
 Module[{labelLst, posSet},
  labelLst = lst /. e_HoldForm :> RandomReal[];
  posSet = Position[labelLst, #][[1]] & /@ Flatten[labelLst];
  ReplacePart[lst, Function[pos, pos -> StringJoin[Flatten@{
            ConstantArray["\t", Length[pos] - 1],
            StringTake[
             ToString[lst[[##]] & @@ pos, InputForm], {10, -2}]
            }]] /@ posSet] // Flatten // Riffle[#, "\n"] & // StringJoin
  ]
```

Example:

```
traceRes = Trace[Reduce[x^2 == -1, x], TraceInternal -> True, TraceDepth -> 3];
Export["tracePrintTest.txt", levelIndentFunc@traceRes, "String"]
```

Open *tracePrintTest.txt* in external text viewer (here *Sublime Text* with [Mathematica syntax highlight plugin](https://github.com/shadanan/mathematica-tmbundle)):

[image: traceprint]

**Edit:**

With the help of Mr.Wizard's `MapIndexed` function, the formatting function `levelIndentFunc` can be simplified to

```
Clear[levelIndentFunc]
levelIndentFunc[lst_] :=
 MapIndexed[
    {ConstantArray["\t", Length[#2] - 1], #1, "\n"} &,
    lst /. e_HoldForm :> StringTake[ToString[e, InputForm], {10, -2}],
    {-1}] // Flatten // StringJoin
```

Comment: Have you looked at `MapIndexed`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks! Almost forgot it can scan different levels!

Comment: Glad I could jog your memory. :-)  I added a simplification of your own method that I believe is equivalent.  I hope it helps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you may merely want [`MapIndexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapIndexed.html).  For your first example:

```
lst = {{"X", {{"X", "X"}, {{"X", "X"}, "X"}, "X"}, "X"}, "X", "X"};

f[s_String, pos_] := {Length@pos, s}
f[other_, _] := other

MapIndexed[f, lst, -1]
```

> ```
> {{{2,"X"},{{{4,"X"},{4,"X"}},{{{5,"X"},{5,"X"}},{4,"X"}},{3,"X"}},{2,"X"}},{1,"X"},{1,"X"}}
> ```

Alternatively, your own formulation may be simplified:

```
ReplacePart[lst,
  # -> {Length@#, lst ~Extract~ #} & /@ Position[lst, s_String]
]
```

> ```
> {{{2,"X"},{{{4,"X"},{4,"X"}},{{{5,"X"},{5,"X"}},{4,"X"}},{3,"X"}},{2,"X"}},{1,"X"},{1,"X"}}
> ```

In either method the pattern `s_String` defines which objects are to be indexed.  A simpler/faster method for all atomic objects (level `{-1}`) is:

```
MapIndexed[{Length@#2, #} &, lst, {-1}]
```

> ```
> {{{2,"X"},{{{4,"X"},{4,"X"}},{{{5,"X"},{5,"X"}},{4,"X"}},{3,"X"}},{2,"X"}},{1,"X"},{1,"X"}}
> ```

Comment: Really appreciate! :D

Comment: @Silvia You're welcome.  I made a third update to the question with a simpler form that may or may not be adaptable to your problem.  (Other levelspec values could be used.)

Comment: Thanks. I will `ToString` all atomic objects before feeding to the indent function, so I think all your version will work perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

This obviously can't hold a candle to Mr. Wizard's solutions, and is a bit hackish as well, but anyway:

```
Fold[Replace[#1, "X" -> {#2, "A"}, {#2}] &, lst, 
  Range[Depth[lst] - 1]] /. "A" -> "X"
```

If there's anyway to use this approach without using the dummy symbol, I'd like to know about it. -> Edit: See Mr. Wizard's solution in the comments.

Comment: I always like alternatives. +1  As for eliminating the substitution, how about: `Fold[Replace[#1, "X" -> {#2, "X"}, {#2}] &, lst, Reverse @ Range[Depth[lst] - 1]]` ?  Also, you could use a rule such as `p : "X" :> {#2, p}` which would be useful when not all indexed expressions are identical.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Great "backward" thinking! :D

Comment: :-) By the way, `Reverse @ Range[Depth[lst] - 1]` could be written `Range[Depth[lst] - 1, 1, -1]` as you prefer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Fortunately that's one thing I do know, lol (referring to the negative step in Range). However I still have to work out where the named pattern would come in useful in this type of problem. Could you give an example?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't express myself well.  I mean if e.g. `lst = {{"A", {{"Q", "C"}, {{"J", "M"}, "B"}, "R"}, "I"}, "X", "T"};` and you want to index every string, then:  `Fold[Replace[#1, p_String :> {#2, p}, {#2}] &, lst, Range[Depth[lst] - 1, 1, -1]]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ah, okay. That I know too.

Answer (score 6):

```
lst = {{"X", {{"X", "X"}, {{"X", "X"}, "X"}, "X"}, "X"}, "X", "X"};

SetAttributes[f, Listable]

Map[f, lst, {1, Infinity}];

ClearAttributes[f, Listable]

%% //. {
  f[x_String] :> {1, x},
  f[{i_Integer, x_String}] :> {i + 1, x}}

{{{2, "X"}, {{{4, "X"}, {4, "X"}}, {{{5, "X"}, {5, "X"}}, {4, 
     "X"}}, {3, "X"}}, {2, "X"}}, {1, "X"}, {1, "X"}}
```

Comment: Interesting method!

Comment: You can `MapAll` or `//@` but then set first rule to `{0, x}`.

Comment: Everybody has their unique angle of view on Mathematica. Somebody like "arrows" while somebody prefer "@"s :)

Comment: @Silvia True. I much prefer `MapIndexed` but it's kind of curiosity like you said, `MapAll` useful for once.

Comment: @BoLe Off-topic, but have the GIFs in your blog been generated using _Mathematica_? They're quite cool!

Comment: @Aky Everything M-grown of course. :)

Comment: @BoLe I wish I had your imagination (and your _Mathematica_ skills)! I was especially curious about the jelly-like blobs in your newer ones. Did you use level sets for those? (I'd appreciate it if you could answer in the chat when you have time. I don't want to mess up the comments section of this answer - I guess I'll delete this comment later.)

Comment: @Aky Sure, I can share my secrets. :) Can you make a room or where do you want to chat?

Comment: @BoLe I created a Mathematica room called "BoLe's secrets" :D Don't know if there's an easy way to invite you to it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8986/discussion-between-bole-and-aky)