# Should DSolve always return solution with constant of integration?

Tags: differential-equations, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.0.2**

---

```
Clear[y,x];
DSolve[D[y[x], x] - y[x]^2 + y[x]*Sin[x] - Cos[x] == 0, y[x], x, 
    GeneratedParameters -> C]
```

or

```
DSolve[D[y[x], x] - y[x]^2 + y[x]*Sin[x] - Cos[x] == 0, y[x], x]
```

both return a solution that does not include `C[1]`, the constant of integration.

```
{{y[x] -> Sin[x]}}
```

The question is: Should `DSolve` always return an arbitrary constant? Even though the answer is correct, it is missing `C[1]` hence this is a particular solution.

If `DSolve` does not *have to* generate a constant of integration in the solution of a differential equation, then what caused it not to generate it in this specific case?

**Update:**

Let me add a solution found by Maple for this, which *does* include a constant of integration:

```
Clear[C,y,x];
eq = Derivative[1][y][x] - y[x]^2 + y[x]*Sin[x] - Cos[x] == 0;
eq /. y -> (- Exp[-Cos[#]]/(C[1] + Integrate[ Exp[-Cos[#]], x]) + Sin[#] &);
Simplify[%]
(* True *)
```

So, the above is a general solution with a constant of integration that solves the same differential equation.

Comment: In case it helps, this is a Riccati equation - [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it's a bug.

### Tracing

Tracing the evaluation of `DSolve` as the following:

```
eq = D[y[x], x] - y[x]^2 + y[x]*Sin[x] - Cos[x] == 0;

traceRes = Trace[DSolve[eq, y[x], x, 
                        GeneratedParameters -> ThisIsForGeneralC],
                 {TraceInternal -> True,
                 TraceOff -> _Message}];
```

and formatting (using the `levelIndentFunc` function I mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26056/17)) and exporting the result (it will be around 200 MByte):

```
Export["[Trace-result] DSolve.txt", levelIndentFunc @ traceRes, "String"]
```

Searching the "unique" footprint `ThisIsForGeneralC` we made on purpose, it's not hard to find where the problem comes from.

### Analysis

Here, from the trace result we can see, MMA eventually arrives a point like:

```
DSolve`DSolveFirstOrderODEDump`f = {{{y[x] -> E^Cos[x]*DSolve`DSolveFirstOrderODEDump`const[2] + E^Cos[x]*Integrate[DSolve`DSolveFirstOrderODEDump`const[1]/E^Cos[K[1]], {K[1], 1, x}]}}}
DSolve`DSolveFirstOrderODEDump`f = DSolve`DSolveFirstOrderODEDump`f[[1,1,1,2]]; {DSolve`DSolveFirstOrderODEDump`f, DSolve`DSolveFirstOrderODEDump`g} = {Coefficient[DSolve`DSolveFirstOrderODEDump`f, DSolve`DSolveFirstOrderODEDump`const[1]], Coefficient[DSolve`DSolveFirstOrderODEDump`f, DSolve`DSolveFirstOrderODEDump`const[2]]}; {{y[x] -> -((ThisIsForGeneralC[1]*D[DSolve`DSolveFirstOrderODEDump`f, x] + D[DSolve`DSolveFirstOrderODEDump`g, x])/(DSolve`DSolveFirstOrderODEDump`h*(ThisIsForGeneralC[1]*DSolve`DSolveFirstOrderODEDump`f + DSolve`DSolveFirstOrderODEDump`g)))}}
```

which is actually

```
f = {{{y[x] -> E^Cos[x]*const[2] + E^Cos[x]*Integrate[const[1]/E^Cos[K[1]], {K[1], 1, x}]}}}; 
f = f[[1, 1, 1, 2]]
```

[image: intermedia f]

```
{f, g} = {Coefficient[f, const[1]], Coefficient[f, const[2]]}
{{y[x] -> -((ThisIsForGeneralC[1]*D[f, x] + D[g, x])/(h*(ThisIsForGeneralC[1]*f + g)))}}
```

[image: final false result]

**Note the `f = Coefficient[f, const[1]]` part, which is incorrectly evaluated to `0`! That's the one to blame for our issue!**

If we replace `f` with the correct value:

```
f = E^Cos[x]*Integrate[E^(-Cos[K[1]]), {K[1], 1, x}];
```

We'll get effectively the same general solution as the one mentioned in OP:

```
{{y[x] -> -((ThisIsForGeneralC[1]*D[f, x] + D[g, x])/(h*(ThisIsForGeneralC[1]*f + g)))}}
```

[image: correct result]

Some perhaps fixes coming up to my mind include:

1. Introducing new rule for `Integrate` (Please compare `Integrate[a b[x], {x, 0, 1}]` and `Integrate[a b[x], x]`); Or
2. Introducing new rule for `Coefficient` (Maybe not a good idea); Or
3. Using method other than `Coefficient` in `DSolve`.

Comment: That was very impressive!

Comment: @acl Thanks :D Hope one day we'll have a better tool for this kind of debugging!

Answer (score 11):

This is a bug in DSolve. The solution to your example should
certainly include a constant of integration.

DSolve attempts to solve this Riccati equation by solving the
corresponding second order linear ODE. The problem occurs while
using the solution of the second order linear ODE, which has an 
unevaluated integral in it.

Sorry for the confusion and thanks for reporting the problem.

Comment: Welcome to mathematica.stackexchange! Nice to see you here (We met a few years ago in Champaign :)).

Answer (score 6):

Heureka! Symbolic solution with constant of integration found.
With a little help for MMA from its friend ...

Writing the differential equation as

```
eq = y'[x] - Cos[x] == y[x] (y[x] - Sin[x]);
```

we observe that putting (no MMA code)

$$z(t)=y(t)-Sin(t)$$

we obtain a related equation

```
eq1 = z'[t] == z[t] (z[t] + Sin[t]);
```

which surprisingly is DSolved readily by MMA

```
DSolve[eq1, z[t], t]

{{z[t] -> 1/(E^Cos[t]*(C[1] - Integrate[E^(-Cos[K[1]]), {K[1], 1, t}]))}}
```

and it does contain an arbitrary constant C[1] as it should do. It looks similar to the Maple solution but I have not checked it.

The solution is rather non-trivial as it contains the function

```
f[t_] := Integrate[Exp[-Cos[u]], {u, 0, t}]
```

a special function which is not recognized by Mathematica.

Using NIntegrate we can see that it increases "linearly" with a light "wobble".
This also means that for t->oo the solution of eq1 approaches a "sinusiodal" oscillation symmetrical about z=0.

I can't tell why Mathematica is not "ingenious" enough to spot the simple substitution by itself.

I'll continue a bit an $f(t)$ but for the moment the question seems to be answered.

Regards,
Wolfgang

Comment: For integer k we have f(k pi)/(k pi) = BesselI[0, 1] ~= 1.2660658777520082 which proves the "linear" increase.

Comment: in case you use latex, you can use it here. I've added some markup to your answer.

Comment: @acl: thanks for beautifying my text. Looks really good. Unfortunately I don't have latex.

Answer (score 1):

Bug fixed in 10.0.2

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Clear[y, x];
DSolve[D[y[x], x] - y[x]^2 + y[x]*Sin[x] - Cos[x] == 0, y[x], x, 
      GeneratedParameters -> C]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]