# A simplification of a complex expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

I use mathematica to confirm a result from a paper ("`Unsteady unidirectional flow of Bingham fluid between parallel plates with different given volume flow rate conditions`") which should be simplified to a real expression. However, I have tried many many times but all failed. The following code showed my efforts:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Γ[s_] := Module[{m, delta, ee},
m = Sqrt[s]/Sqrt[ν];

delta = Sinh[m h] Sinh[m h0] - Cosh[m h] Cosh[m h0];

ee = Cosh[m h0] (Sinh[m h] - Sinh[m h0]) - 
Sinh[m h0] (Cosh[m h] - Cosh[m h0]);

(m h  delta)/(
m h delta + m h0 (Cosh[m h0]^2 - Sinh[m h0]^2) + ee) ];

Simplify[Im[
E^( I ω t) Γ[I ω] + 
E^(- I ω t) Γ[-I ω] // ComplexExpand],
TimeConstraint -> Infinity]
```

Actually, the complex expression in the above code is the first term of dp/dx as shown in the following picture, and dp/dx is a pressure gradient which should be a expression of real values. So the image part of this expression should vanish, but the above code gives no result after a hour.

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

**Edit 1: -----------------------------------**

As suggested by @Bob Hanlon, I tried to include all the variable constraints in `Simplify`, but still failed to get a real-valued expression.

```
expr = E^(I \[Omega] t) \[CapitalGamma][I \[Omega]] + E^(- I \[Omega] t) \[CapitalGamma][-I \[Omega]]

Simplify[ComplexExpand[expr], {h > h0 > 0,t > 0, \[Omega] > 0, \[Nu] > 0}]
```

Comment: Other than all the variables/constants -- other than `I` -- being real (implied by your use of `ComplexExpand`), are there any additional known constraints? For example, are any of the variables/constants positive or at least nonnegative? Any known constraints should be included in the `Simplify` or wrap the `Simplify` with `Assuming`.

Comment: Why not trying a simpler case of t=0 ?

Comment: The result should be zero. As your function Gamma[s]  is a real function of s for all parameters being real the expression which you wish to simplify (with t and omega real as well)  is the real part of some quantity. This is of course a real quantity, hence its imaginary part is zero.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon, thanks for the kind response. Including additional constraints seems to not work, as shown in my edit above.

Comment: @yachik, thanks, I guess maybe the only way to obtain the real valued expression is to replace variables with their numeric values, and a full symbolic real valued expression may not be achieved.

Comment: @ Dr. Wolfgang Hintze, thanks. Yes the imaginary part should be zero. But what I really expect is the final symbolic real valued result of this complex expression.

Comment: @xzczd, thanks for the quick response :). I want to know whether it is possible to simplify the first term of dp/dx ( i.e., just the term in the red rectangle in the first picture, not the whole expression of dp/dx) to a real-valued result.

Comment: Doesn't manage to find a solution so far, but given the experience gained in [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/109988/1871) and [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109733/1871) post, I guess some clever change of variable may help.

Comment: Just to confirm: the minimum goal of this question, is to prove the expression is real-valued, right?

Comment: @xzczd,  I will check these two posts and try method of change of variable. Again, thanks for your time. :)

Comment: @xzczd,  the minimum goal is to prove the imaginary part is zero, and the final goal is to find the real part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key idea of this solution is to partly simplify the expression by direct substitution of some known terms rather than using functions for simplification like `Simplify`.

First, take out the imaginary part of the expression and observe:

```
impart = E^(I ω t) Γ[I ω] + E^(-I ω t) Γ[-I ω] // Im // ComplexExpand
```

[image]

Hmm… seems that there're many `Arg` terms in `impart`. It's natural to guess these terms will slow down the simplification process of `Simplify`. Let's check what kind of `Arg` term is contained in `impart` further:

```
cons = {h > h0 > 0, t > 0, ω > 0, ν > 0};
Cases[impart, Arg[_], Infinity] // Union
(* {Arg[ν], Arg[-I ω], Arg[I ω]} *)
imrule = # -> Simplify[#, cons] &@% // Thread
(* {Arg[ν] -> 0, Arg[-I ω] -> -(π/2), Arg[I ω] -> π/2} *)
```

There're 3 different `Arg` terms, whose values are known under the constraints. Plug them back to `impart`:

```
immid = impart /. imrule;
```

and simplify:

```
Simplify[immid, cons]
(* 0 *)
```

OK, the minimum goal is achieved, and with the same method, the final goal i.e. find the free-of-`I` form of the expression can be achieved, too:

```
repart = E^(I ω t) Γ[I ω] + E^(-I ω t) Γ[-I ω] // Re // ComplexExpand;

Cases[repart, Arg[_], Infinity] // Union
(* {Arg[ν], Arg[-I ω], Arg[I ω]} *)
rerule = # -> Simplify[#, cons] &@% // Thread
(* {Arg[ν] -> 0, Arg[-I ω] -> -(π/2), Arg[I ω] -> π/2} *)

remid = repart /. rerule;

Simplify[remid, cons] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {16.001111, …… *)
```

The result is a little long so I'd like to omit it here.

Comment: what can I say. Perfect!!! Especially the detailed process to attack the problem, very valuable.Before saw your solution, I started to thinking quit eveytime I met a very long out in Mathematica.  I really appreciate your time!