# Fill an empty matrix with the depth of its elements

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, challenge-community

Given an arbitrarily nested empty matrix like for example

```
mat =
  {
   {},
   {{}, {}},
   {{}, {{}}, {}},
   {{}, {{}}, {}, {{{}}}}
   };
```

and knowing that

```
Depth /@ mat
```

{2, 3, 4, 5}

**Question 1**

how can I produce the following result?

```
res =
  {
   {2},
   {{3}, {3}},
   {{3}, {{4}}, {3}},
   {{3}, {{4}}, {3}, {{{5}}}}
   };
```

**Question 2**

Given

```
{{2}, {3, 3}, {3, 4, 3}, {3, 4, 3, 5}};
```

how can I produce the above empty matrix `mat` ?

Comment: **Challenge** : How many different ways can we achieve this? [tag:challenge-community]

Comment: Similar to [26056](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26056/numbering-nested-list-according-with-depth-or-level).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Q1

#### My original answer

Using [`ReplacePart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplacePart.html), [`Length`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Length.html) and [`Position`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html)

```
res === ReplacePart[
    mat, 
    # -> {1+Length[#]}& /@ Position[mat, {} ]
]
(* True *)
```

#### My [`MapIndexed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html)attempt

I liked the solutions by @kglr and @lericr, so my version of it (*) is:

```
res === (
     MapIndexed[ {1 + Length[#2]}&, mat, {-2} ]
)
(* True *)
```

<sub>* (In the spirit of the saying that *plagiarism is the best form of flattery*.)</sub>

## Q2

Using [`Nest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html), [`List`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html), [`Nothing`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html) and [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) (`/.`)

```
mat === (
    {
        {2}, 
        {3, 3}, 
        {3, 4, 3}, 
        {3, 4, 3, 5}
    } /. x_Integer :> Nest[List, Nothing, x-2 ]
)
(* True *)
```

Comment: `Nest[List, Nothing, x-2 ]` - so simple and yet: Probably I would never have found it

Answer (score 6):

#### Q1:

#### [MapIndexed](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html)

```
MapIndexed[# /. {} -> 1 + {Length @ #2} &, mat, All]
```

> ```
>  {{2}, {{3}, {3}}, {{3}, {{4}}, {3}}, {{3}, {{4}}, {3}, {{{5}}}}}
> ```

#### [Position](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html) + [ReplaceAll](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html)

```
$i = 0;
mat2 = mat /. {} :> {++$i};

mat2 /. i_Integer :> Length @ First @ Position[mat2, i]
```

> ```
>  {{2}, {{3}, {3}}, {{3}, {{4}}, {3}}, {{3}, {{4}}, {3}, {{{5}}}}}
> ```

#### Internal`CopyListStructure + [Position](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html)

```
Internal`CopyListStructure[mat /. {}->{1}, 1 + Map[Length] @ Position[mat, {}]]
```

> ```
>   {{2}, {{3}, {3}}, {{3}, {{4}}, {3}}, {{3}, {{4}}, {3}, {{{5}}}}}
> ```

#### Q2:

#### [FixedPoint](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FixedPoint.html) + [ReplaceAll](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html)

```
depths = {{2}, {3, 3}, {3, 4, 3}, {3, 4, 3, 5}};

FixedPoint[ReplaceAll[{0 -> Nothing, i_Integer :> {i - 1}}], depths - 2]
```

> ```
> {{}, {{}, {}}, {{}, {{}}, {}}, {{}, {{}}, {}, {{{}}}}}
> ```

```
 % == mat
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Using [ReplaceAll](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html?q=ReplaceAll)(/.) & [Depth](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Depth.html?q=Depth)

**Q1:**

```
res === Map[# /. {} -> Depth@# &, mat /. {} -> {{}}, {2}]
(*True*)
```

Using [ReplaceRepeated](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html?q=ReplaceRepeated)

**Q2**

```
input = {
    {2}, 
    {3, 3}, 
    {3, 4, 3}, 
    {3, 4, 3, 5}
};
mat === Map[
    {e} |-> {e} //. {e_?Positive -> List[e - 1], {{{0}}} -> Nothing}, input, {2}]
(*True*)
```

Comment: AFAICS, the input for **Q2** is not `res` but `Flatten/@ res`.

Comment: @rhermans Thx, I did not pay enough attention. I deleted the second part.

Comment: No problem, you can still add to it. (+1)

Answer (score 5):

## Q1

```
1 + MapIndexed[List@*Length@*Last, mat, {-2}]
```

## Q2

```
Map[Nest[List, Nothing, # - 2] &, input, {-1}]
```