# Converting two lists into a list of tuples

Tags: list-manipulation

I wonder how I can turn the list $\{a_1,...,a_n\}$ into the new list $\{(a_1,1),...,(a_n,n)\}$, i.e $a_k \mapsto (a_k,k)$, how do I do that?

I figured the function Tuples might work, but it just lists all tuples $(a_i,j)$, $i,j \in [n]$. Can't seem to find any other function that accomplishes what I want. Thanks.

Comment: Related: [(3585)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3585/121); this is essentially a simpler version of that question.

Comment: I found a closer one.  Closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n = 5;

list = Array[a, n];

Thread[{list, Range[Length[list]]}]
```

> {{a[1], 1}, {a[2], 2}, {a[3], 3}, {a[4], 4}, {a[5], 5}}

EDIT (addressing additional question in OP comment): If m and n are known:

```
m = 10; n = 6;

list = Array[a, n];

Thread[{list, Range[m - n + 1, m]}]
```

> {{a[1], 5}, {a[2], 6}, {a[3], 7}, {a[4], 8}, {a[5], 9}, {a[6], 10}}

Comment: Thanks! Now, what if the second list is not $\{1,...n\}$ but $\{m-(n-1),m-(n-2),...,m\}$, $m>n$?

Answer (score 4):

I've often wondered what the best approach is for this.  I find myself combining two lists `a` and `b` of the same length in this way quite frequently.  I have always used `Transpose[{a,b}]`, but wondered if that was the most efficient way to do it.  It seems like it would require moving around a lot of stuff in memory.

So I tested the speed of the solutions shown here, as well as checked whether they preserved packed arrays.

```
Needs["Developer`"]
a=RandomInteger[1000000000,1000000];
b=Range[1000000];
PackedArrayQ@a
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
PackedArrayQ@b
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
Timing[c=Thread[{a,b}];]
PackedArrayQ@c
```

> ```
> {0.278477,Null}
> False
> ```

```
Timing[c=Transpose[{a,b}];]
PackedArrayQ@c
```

> ```
> {0.011906,Null}
> True
> ```

```
Timing[c=MapIndexed[{#1,First@#2}&,a];]
PackedArrayQ@c
```

> ```
> {1.256647,Null}
> False
> ```

```
Timing[c=MapThread[List,{a,b}];]
PackedArrayQ@c
```

> ```
> {0.371252,Null}
> False
> ```

```
Timing[c=Inner[List,a,b,List];]
PackedArrayQ@c
```

> ```
> {0.274188,Null}
> False
> ```

I had high hopes for `Thread`.  However `Transpose` is the clear winner, and the only one that preserves packed arrays.

Any other solutions we should try?

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient way should be this (because of `Transpose`):

```
n = 10;
list = Array[a, n]
Transpose[{ list, Range @ Length[list]}]
```

> ```
> {a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8], a[9], a[10]}
> ```

```
 {{a[1], 1}, {a[2], 2}, {a[3], 3}, {a[4], 4}, {a[5], 5}, 
  {a[6], 6}, {a[7], 7}, {a[8], 8}, {a[9], 9}, {a[10], 10}}
```

For certain similar functionality look e.g. at `Tally`, `BinLists`, `BinCounts`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option:

```
n=5;
list=RandomInteger[10,n];
MapIndexed[{#1,First@#2}&,list]
```

> {{10,1},{4,2},{8,3},{2,4},{1,5}}

Comment: We came on with the same solution nearly at the same time :-)

Comment: @mgamer ...  technically it's mine by 3 minutes.. :)

Comment: Your are absolutely right! :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to accomplish this, one of them is also MapIndexed:

```
list = RandomInteger[{1, 20}, 10]
```

and then

```
MapIndexed[{#1, First @ #2} &, list]
```

Comment: This is the same answer I posted..

Comment: Yes, I just saw it - browser updates in intervals, so I did not see your answer... I was typing in the same moment *funny*

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want:

```
Module[{i = 1},
 {#, i++} & /@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10]
]
```

You need to localise the `i` iterator so that it works on multiple occasions. If you didn't do this, the second column would start at whatever the length of the previous list was.

It should be noted that this method performs similarly to, but a bit more slowly than, the `MapIndexed` solution proposed by others.

```
list = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 1000000];

Module[{i = 1}, {#, i++} & /@ list]; // Timing

(*{0.967206, Null}*)

MapIndexed[{#1, First@#2} &, list]; // Timing

(*{0.904806, Null} *)
```