# Checking if one partition is a subpartition of another

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics, partitions

Say I've got two partitions of a list (not necessarily containing numbers, and not necessarily distinct), and I want to check that one is a subpartition of the other. Let's look at some examples:

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
p1 = {{1,   2,   3}, {4,   5,   6}};
p2 = {{1}, {2,   3}, {4,   5}, {6}};
p3 = {{1,   2}, {3,   4}, {5,   6}};

subpartitionQ[p1, p2] (* True *)
subpartitionQ[p1, p3] (* False *)
```

The second is a subpartition of the first in that the first can be formed by joining some consecutive subsets of the second back together. Note that this is not possible with `p3`: this one contains `3` and `4` in the same sublist, whereas `p1` doesn't, so I can't recover `p1` merely by joining consecutive sublists.

Note that I also can't check whether all lists of `pn` are subsets of some sublist of `p1`, because the elements aren't necessarily distinct. E.g. `list` could also have been `{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}`. This is only about the *structure* of the partitions.

Of course I could get all partitions of `pn`, join each segment together and check if one of them is equal to `p1` but that seems horribly inefficient and inelegant. Are there better ways to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes you just need to think about it for 5 more minutes... I just found a solution myself which I think is fairly elegant:

```
subpartitionQ[p1_,p2_] := SubsetQ[Accumulate[Length /@ p2], Accumulate[Length /@ p1]]
```

The idea is to check that the lengths of the subpartition need to sum to all the lengths in the superpartition at some point. The preprocessing step `Accumulate[Length /@ pn]` turns the three partitions from the question into

```
{3, 6}
{1, 3, 5, 6}
{2, 4, 6}
```

respectively. We can now see that the `3` from `p1` is missing in `p3` which indicates that this is *not* a subpartition, whereas `p2` contains both `3` and `6`.

If someone has a better solution, I'd still be very interested!

Comment: You can implement a Bloom filter:

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter

Comment: "If someone has a better solution, I'd still be very interested!" <-- I think this is the best solution.  I think of the partition as a set of dividers within the list.  You just need to check whether all the dividers in `p1` are also in `p2`.  This is exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Using the function `CoarserSetPartitionQ` from the `Combinatorica` package with a function that numbers elements consecutively while keeping the structure of a nested list ([see, e.g., this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3589/125)):

```
numbering[x_]:= Block[{n = 0}, Map[++n &, x, {-1}]]

Needs["Combinatorica`"]
refinementQ = With[{a = numbering@#, b= numbering@#2}, CoarserSetPartitionQ[b, a]] &;
```

Examples:

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
p1 = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
p2 = {{1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6}};
p3 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
{p1b, p2b, p3b} = Map[1 &, #, {-1}] & /@ {p1, p2, p3}
(* {{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}}}*)

refinementQ @@@ {{p1, p2}, {p1, p3}, {p1b, p2b}, {p1b, p3b}}
(* {True, False, True, False} *)
```