# Combining lists of lists with random structure

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists which I would like to combine. One is of a random structure, which might be:

```
l1={{3, 2, 4, 2}, {2, 3}, {4, 3}, {{2, 2}}, {{3, 3}}, {3, 2}}
```

where the elements in each sublist may themselves be numbers, or lists.

From this, I create a list given by:

```
l2=Join[{0}, Accumulate[Flatten[l1, 1]]]
```

which gives in this case:

```
{0, 3, 5, 9, 11, 13, 16, 20, 23, {25, 25}, {28, 28}, {31, 31}, {33, 33}}
```

I now want to go through the original list, and append to each entry in that list, an entry from the second, in order, to end up with:

```
{{{3, 0}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {2, 9}}, {{2, 11}, {3, 13}}, {{4, 16}, {3, 20}}, {{{2, 2}, 23}}, {{{3, 3}, {25, 25}}}, {{3, {28, 28}}, {2, {31, 31}}}}
```

I can do this using a loop, but I would like to find a functional way to write it. I have tried using various map, list and thread commands, but so far have been unable to solve it.

Comment: Related: [(3585)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3585/121)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This matches your output:

```
Module[{i = 1},
  Map[{#, l2[[i++]]} &, l1, {2}]
]
```

If you don't need `l2` separately you can eliminate the use of `Accumulate` entirely with:

```
Module[{t = 0},
  Map[{#, # &[t, t += #]} &, l1, {2}]
]
```

The inner function `# &[t, t += #]` is just a way to [`AddTo`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AddTo.html) `t` but return the old value of `t`.  Equivalently: `First[{t, t += #}]`.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you!

Comment: @Jonathan You're welcome, and I am glad I could help.  As always however I recommend waiting 24 hours before Accepting an answer to encourage everyone who has an answer to post it.

Comment: @Jonathan Please see my update.

Comment: thanks for the tip. regarding accepting the answer. I shall keep this in mind in the future. Indeed I don't need the intermediate step, so the update is very useful too.

Answer (score 6):

Also,

```
l3 = Internal`PartitionRagged[Most@l2, Length /@ l1];
Transpose /@ Transpose[{l1, l3}]
```

> {{{3, 0}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {2, 9}},
>        {{2, 11}, {3, 13}},
>        {{4, 16}, {3, 20}},
>        {{{2, 2}, 23}},
>        {{{3, 3}, {25, 25}}},
>        {{3, {28, 28}}, {2, {31, 31}}}}

Answer (score 2):

[image]

**Using `TakeList`:**

```
l1 = {{3, 2, 4, 2}, {2, 3}, {4, 3}, {{2, 2}}, {{3, 3}}, {3, 2}};
l2 = Join[{0}, Accumulate[Flatten[l1, 1]]];

Thread[{l1, TakeList[l2, Length /@ l1]}] // Map[Transpose]
```

> {{{3, 0}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {2, 9}}, {{2, 11}, {3, 13}}, {{4, 16}, {3,
> 20}}, {{{2, 2},     23}}, {{{3, 3}, {25, 25}}}, {{3, {28, 28}}, {2,
> {31, 31}}}}

Answer (score 2):

Using `MapThread` and `FoldPairList`, an equivalent form to the one proposed by @Syed is the following:

```
l1 = {{3, 2, 4, 2}, {2, 3}, {4, 3}, {{2, 2}}, {{3, 3}}, {3, 2}};
l2 = Join[{0}, Accumulate[Flatten[l1, 1]]];
l3 = Length /@ l1;

MapThread[Transpose@List[#1, #2] &, {l1, FoldPairList[TakeDrop, l2, l3]}]
```

> { {{3, 0}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {2, 9}}, {{2, 11}, {3, 13}}, {{4, 16}, {3, 20}}, {{{2, 2}, 23}},
> {{{3, 3}, {25, 25}}, {{3, {28, 28}}, {2, {31, 31}}}} }

Comment: The `FoldPairList` technique is in the docs as an equivalent to `TakeList`. I still struggle with the use of `FoldPairList` though.

Comment: The same thing happens to me, that's why I always pay attention to the posts where there's manipulation of lists.