# Function to draw densely interconnected layers in graph (e.g., neural net)

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, functional-style

I can use `Graph[]` to manually draw the shape of a very simple set of interconnected layers (for instance, a small neural network):

```
Graph[{1 -> 3, 2 -> 3, 1 -> 5, 2 -> 5, 1 -> 4, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 6, 4 -> 6, 5 -> 6}]
```

produces:

[image]

How can I programmatically generate the list of connections from a list of layer sizes? For instance, the above would be: `layerCounts = { 2, 3, 1}` and I'm hoping for a function `Dense` that might be invoked like `Graph[Dense[layerCounts]]`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This one constructs an `AdjacencyMatrix` that can be input to `AdjacencyGraph`:

```
f = Module[{index = {1, 1 + First@#}},
    AdjacencyGraph @ SparseArray[Band[# &[index, index += #]] ->
         ConstantArray[1, #] & /@ Partition[#, 2, 1], {1, 1} Total@#]] &;
```

where the function `# &[index, index += #]` is from [this post by Mr.Wizard.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/135239/125)

**Examples:**

```
f@{4, 3, 3, 2, 1}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
SetProperty[f[{5, 3, 1, 3, 5}] ,
 {VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> Large, VertexLabelStyle -> 20}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
SetProperty[f[#]  , {VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center],
    GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding", "VertexPartition" -> #},
    VertexSize -> Large, VertexLabelStyle -> 14}] &@ RandomInteger[{1, 5}, 10]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Congratulations on breaking 100K. :D

Comment: Yes, Happy 100K :)

Answer (score 11):

There might be a built-in that would simplify this, but if not this should get the job done:

```
fn[lc : {__Integer?Positive}] :=
 Join @@ Tuples /@ 
    Rule @@@ Partition[Internal`PartitionRagged[Range@Tr@lc, lc], 2, 1] // Graph

fn[{2, 3, 1}]
```

[image]

A bit shorter of node names may be arbitrary:

```
fn[lc : {__Integer?Positive}] :=
 Join @@ Tuples /@ Rule @@@ Partition[MapIndexed[#2 &, Range@lc, {2}], 2, 1] // Graph
```

Comment: Beautiful, thanks!