# Replace heads to match a pattern

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

Is it possible to replace the heads to match a pattern?

eg

```
f[f[f[]]]    ->   a[b[c[]]]
```

or

```
f[f[], f[]]  ->   a[b[], c[]]
```

I looked [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56010/using-replaceall-to-replace-a-head), but though it is related, I can't seem to apply it to this problem.

Comment: Kinda hacky but `In[76]:= heads = {a, b, c};
j = 0;
ReplaceAll[f[f[f[]]], f :> (j++; heads[[j]])]

Out[78]= a[b[c[]]]`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau that's nice - it works! Why not post as answer?

Comment: Possibly related: [(3585)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3585/121), [(3858)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3858/121)

Comment: As far as I can tell, most of the answers will also replace `f` if it doesn't appear as the head of an expression, e.g. `f[f, f]` --> `a[b, c]`. Is that your intention?

Comment: @MartinEnder for my purposes, the answers given so far meet my needs. It would be nice to have an answer that deals with this issue though!

Comment: @martin Some answers using `ReplaceAll` can be modified by changing `/. f :> new` to `//. f[args___] :> new[args]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 great thanks - will give it a go :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
replaceHeads[expr_, h_, new_] := 
 ReplacePart[expr, Thread[Position[expr, h] -> new]]
replaceHeads[f[f[f[]]], f, {a, b, c}]
(*a[b[c[]]]*)
replaceHeads[f[f[], f[]], f, {a, b, c}]
(*a[b[], c[]]*)
```

Comment: nice, thanks :)

Comment: This answer could be restricted to actually only matching *heads* by wrapping `Position[...]` in `Cases[..., {___, 0}]`.

Answer (score 6):

Quick and dirty:

```
replaceHeadWithSet[expr_, h_, heads_] := Module[{j = 0},
  ReplaceAll[expr, 
   h :> (j = Mod[j + 1, Length[heads], 1]; heads[[j]])]]

Example:

replaceHeadWithSet[f[f[f[], f[]]], f, {a, b, c}]

(* Out[84]= a[b[c[], a[]]] *)
```

Answer (score 5):

A different interpretation: the heads to replace are not all the same but the structure is fixed.

```
rep[h_@x___, {n_, r___}] := n @ rep[x, {r}]

rep[x___, {}] := x
```

Use:

```
rep[f[g[h[]]], {a, b, c}]
```

> ```
> a[b[c[]]]
> ```

Comment: great - thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

Using [`Iterator`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135916/how-to-use-the-iterator-in-mathematica), while it lasts:

```
With[{foo = GeneralUtilities`ListIterator[{a, b, c}]},
 f[f[f[]]] /. f :> Read[foo]]
(*  a[b[c[]]]  *)
```

Without `foo`:

```
f[f[], f[]] /. f :> Read[#] &@GeneralUtilities`ListIterator[{a, b, c}]
(*  a[b[], c[]]  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Fold[Replace[#1, f[expr___] -> #2[[1]][expr], {#2[[2]]}] &, f[f[f[]]], 
{{a, 0}, {b, 1}, {c, 2}}]

(* a[b[c[]]] *)
```

however since we are replacing all the heads iteratively at each level, the current approach will substitute the same head at every level. If you dont mind having the same head for each level then one can use the approach mentioned below

```
Fold[Replace[#1, f[expr___] -> #2[[1]][expr], {#2[[2]]}] &, f[f[],f[]], {{a, 0}, {b, 1}}]

(* a[b[], b[]] *)
```